# Is it worthwhile to create a custom Angular component library based on Angular Material for use across multiple Angular projects of varying versions?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, angular-library

I'm considering the posibility of developing a custom Angular component library built upon Angular Material. This library would be intended for use across several Angular projects with differing versions. However, I'm uncertain whether the effort involved in creating and maintaining such a library for distinct version compatibility would outweigh the benefits of directly utilizing Angular Material in each individual project. Can anyone provide insights into the advantages and disadvantages of developing a custom component library in this context? Additionally, what factors should I consider when making this decision, particularly regarding compatibility, scalability, and maintenance? And algo if it's better to deploy in npm repo or let in a private repository?

So far, I have been installing the specified version of Angular Material in my Angular projects. However, I believe that by creating a small library with the most commonly used components, I could cover many use cases and streamline future development. Additionally, gradually establishing a certain brand image. However, what concerns me the most is the dependency on Angular Material and the limitations it may impose.